# Picard group of Drinfeld upper half space

Tags: reference-request, rigid-analytic-geometry, picard-group

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field and $\Omega^{(n)}_K$ the $n$-dimensional Drinfeld upper half space over $K$ (which is a rigid analytic space over $K$).

> Is the Picard group of $\Omega^{(n)}_K$ known? More generally, I would like to know
>   the Picard group of $\Omega^{(n)}_K$ base changed to any finite extension $L$ of $K$ (which is not the same as $\Omega^{(n)}_L$).

I'd appreciate any references where this question, or similar questions, are considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.12729) paper of Junger, all these Picard groups are shown to be zero.

I think this was known for a long time for $n=1$, see for example the book *Rigid Analytic Geometry and its Applications* by Fresnel and van der Put.